# Php: Find items that match your search in Json

Tags: php, json

I am having a problem doing the search in php.

For example, the last two do not appear in the search, however, the others do appear as a result.

I don't know what I am failing, since I am a beginner in PHP.

When I do the search:
http://localhost/json_api/Pagination.php?search=Lisbety

It does not return the name, however, with others yes, I hope to solve this problem, thank you very much.

**results.json**:

```
{
  "0": {
    "nombre": "Domingo",
    "id": 0
  },
  "4": {
    "nombre": "Jonatan",
    "id": 4
  },
  "5": {
    "nombre": "Inmaculada",
    "id": 5
  },
  "6": {
    "nombre": "Pedro",
    "id": 6
  },
  "7": {
    "nombre": "Mara",
    "id": 7
  },
  "8": {
    "nombre": "Jack",
    "id": 8
  },
  "9": {
    "nombre": "Tyler",
    "id": 9
  },
  "10": {
    "nombre": "Gloria",
    "id": 10
  },
  "11": {
    "nombre": "Alex",
    "id": 11
  },
  "12": {
    "nombre": "Andrea",
    "id": 12
  },
  "13": {
    "nombre": "Luis",
    "id": 13
  },
  "14": {
    "nombre": "Juan",
    "id": 14
  },
  "15": {
    "nombre": "Jose",
    "id": 15
  },
  "16": {
    "nombre": "Luisa",
    "id": 16
  },
  "17": {
    "nombre": "Lisbety",
    "id": 17
  }
}
```

**Pagination.php**:

```
<?php

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');

    $search = $_REQUEST['search'];
    $page = $_REQUEST['page'];
    $per_page = $_REQUEST['per_page'];


    $data_results = file_get_contents('results.json');

    $raw_data = json_decode($data_results, true);

    paginate($raw_data, $page, $per_page, $search);

    function paginate($data, $page, $per_page, $search){
        if(empty($search)){
            echo json_encode(array_slice($data, $page*$per_page, $per_page), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        } else { 
            $i = 0;
            $max = sizeof($data);
            $a = array();
            for($i=0; $i<$max; $i++){
                if(preg_match("/{$search}/i", $data[$i]['nombre'])) {
                    $nombre = array('nombre'=> $data[$i]['nombre'], 'id'=> $data[$i]['id']);
                    array_push($a, $nombre);
                }
            }
            echo json_encode($a, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
        }

    }

?>
```

Comment: I think the issue is your manually built `foreach` function. Take a look at the PHP one, https://3v4l.org/94ZaB.

Comment: ^ Yes, because the indexes are not consistent

Comment: Thank you very much I will keep it in mind.